# Убрать дубли вывода foreach при explode обработке данных

Tags: php, mysql

```
$res = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `cont` FROM `test` ORDER BY `id`");
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
       $str = explode(',', $row['cont']);
       foreach($str as $k) {?>

       <p><?php print_r($k);?></p>

       <?php }} ?>
```

в таблице test - cont содержит

1. lorem,ipsum,dolor
2. ipsum,dolor,sit
3. dolor,sit,amet

Как избавиться от дублей при выводе?

Единственный вариант, как я вижу, вывод foreach собрать в одномерный массив и провести через array_unique.

Если проводить array($k), то создается многомерный массив типа ([0] => lorem [0] => ipsum), array_merge при array($k) ничего все равно не меняет, а без array($k) возникает что объект не массив. array_push - выдает на выходе числа 2 2 2 2.

Нужно чтобы в итоге был вывод такой lorem, ipsum, sit, amet

Comment: какой версии mysql ?

Comment: Версия MySQL 5.6.31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

первый вариант - доработать ваш код, как вы и пишите:

```
 $str[] = explode(....);
 $result = array_unique(array_merge(...$str));
```

второй вариант: сначала собрать строку в цикле, потом сделать explode.

```
$str .= $row['cont'] . ",";
...
$result = array_unique(explode(....)); // появится пустая строка в конце
```

третий вариант  - собрать длинную строку на стороне БД

```
$sql = "select group_concat(DISTINCT cont SEPARATOR ',') as cont from ...";
```

получите одну строку в результате выборки сразу и без объединений на уровне php. Потом так же сделаете `explode` и `unique`.

четвертый вариант - полностью разрулить задачу на стороне СУБД и получить сразу нужный результат.

Можно рассмотреть варианты решения в завимости от того, сколько там у вас данных. Если в таблице пара строк, то можете решать на стороне пхп. Если в базе данных побольше - переносите решение на СУБД.

В любом случае, если у вас возникают подобные вопросы - задумайтесь о приведении своей БД в *нормальную форму*. Тут явно напрашивается отношение *многие-ко-многим*.  Поэтому пока не поздно, переделайте структуру вашей БД и избавьтесь от подобного варианта хранения значений. Это будет правильнее чем любой из вышеперечисленных способов.

Comment: спасибо за разъяснения. Согласен, когда БД сама обрабатывает так безопаснее и быстрее, чем выгонять обработку наружу. Но пока изучаю php и его нюансы и застреваю периодически, так как не хватает знаний программиста (точнее возникает непонимание терминологий), сам специализируюсь на разных видах дизайна, а языки кода изучаю для расширения кругозора и чтобы если делать дизайн сайта удобным не только для пользователя, но и верстальщиков.